# How to persist the state of injected content script even after the page reloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension screen recorder, and whenever the user clicks on the extension, it generates a popup (`popup.js`) which has a button to inject a floating button to the user's current web page.
After the user clicks on the Record button inside the web page, it starts the recording for that page, but when the user clicks on a link or navigates to a different page, the content script gets removed and the recording stops.
I have tested a few other screen-recording chrome extension and when the user navigates to a link or reload the screen kept recording and a stop button kept injected at the bottom of the page.

How can I keep recording the screen / keep the injects code alive even when the user navigates or open a new link?

Comment: Persisting the state won't help, the recording code should be outside the page, they probably use chrome.tabCapture in the background script or in a separate floating window.

Comment: @wOxxOm, So I find a fix for the tabCapture problem, I used `chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId` in the popup.js to get the current tab stream id and then pass that to content script and used `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to record the screen of the current tab. It worked. Do you think there is something wrong in this method?